# How to debug app without rebuilding

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I have a crash that does not happen after the app is built and run, but occurs when I close it and re-open it. How do I run an app in debug mode without building it every time?

Comment: if your app is terminated the debug session ends until to rebuild the app again with starting a new debug session.

Comment: If i do not change any files, why does it rebuild before debug?  Why can't it just install and debug.? I don't understand this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. option+command+R. Didn't solve my problem though, so I'll have to try something else.